# What is inside the overhead compartments in crew dragon

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2, storage

During the DEMO-2 live stream there was a black section visible above the heads of the astronauts. In an image tweeted out by Elon these were labeled as “9” and “10” with symbols of water droplets.

What is inside these compartments? My first assumption was, that it was a toilet, although [this source](https://www.quora.com/How-will-astronauts-be-able-to-go-to-the-bathroom-inside-Crew-Dragon-and-Starliner?share=1) claims there is none. Is it cargo for the ISS? If so why do the compartments require the symbol? Is it drinking water for the flight? Why is it so much? The astronauts are expected to be alone in the capsule for less then a day during their entire trip. Is it maintenance access to the life support system?

[image]

Comment: The Quora claim is wrong. There is a toilet, but at the moment we aren't being told exactly how it works or where it is. The only real clue we have right now is that: "I don't know if the toilet is really cool, necessarily, but it is there. I can tell you it's located — in one-G— would be towards the ceiling. But of course in zero-G, that doesn't matter." by Garrett Reisman who's worked on the capsule with SpaceX. https://www.businessinsider.com/spacex-crew-dragon-spaceship-ceiling-toilet-mystery-proprietary-design-2020-5 . It's very possible that those panels do hide the toilet.

Comment: The Dragon is going to take less than a day to reach the ISS, but there are much longer duration missions being planned.

Comment: That droplet could also be a blood drop, i.e., for a first aid kit.

Answer (score -2):

The overhead compartment is for the First Aid kit and maybe for water as well. Let's have a closer look at the overhead compartment, in this image nor the icons on the compartment itself nor the placing of the compartment can be understood. So we will choose another [video](https://youtu.be/llbIzbOStt4) from the same mission, where we can where it is located. As we can see the compartment is placed on the side of the crew dragon in a very narrow spot. Even if we had information about if there is a toilet in the crew dragon, it would not be located there. So let's look at another [video](https://youtu.be/j2C9DYYVEBk?t=76) from astronaut training. Here we can see the Icon more clearly, obviously, we have a FirstAid kit icon and droplet icon. We do not have any information about the droplet icon or the numbering, however, the FirstAid kit icon is self-explanatory.